# Manipulating PowerPoint with Javascript Add-in?

Tags: office-js

I am trying to make a PowerPoint Web Add-in. I have read the [Office JavaScript API documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office) but it wasn't very detailed.

Do you know functions that permit to:

- Create a new slide programmatically by an Office Add-in
- Add text areas inside a slide programmatically by an Office Add-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to insert a new slide into a PowerPoint presentation at the moment. You can only navigate between existing slides using [Document.goToByIdAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.gotobyidasync).

It is possible to insert a text block or image into an existing slide however. This is done using the [Document.setSelectedDataAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync) method.

For example:

```js
function writeText() {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello World!",
        function (asyncResult) {
            var error = asyncResult.error;
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
            }
        });
}
```

PowerPoint has been notoriously behind the other Office applications in terms of Add-in API functionality. I would highly recommending visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestions (and voting up others). This will be super helpful when it comes to making a case for future investment into PPT API functionality.

Comment: OK - a complementary question : if you have a template, for example with a Title, a Text area and an Image area. Is it possible today to programmatically fill them ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, there is no way to iterate through the existing objects. This is a great suggestion for the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).